# A split image can't be merged after performing a .dot on any of the split bands using pillow/numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to correct the color in images using pillow and numpy. Using im.split() in combination with np.array.

I would like to multiply all colours in the red band, but can't find a way of doing it.

I've tried all kinds of things and after a lot of googling had hoped that this would be the solution:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im=Image.open('test.jpg')
r,g,b=im.split() 

datar = np.array(r)
datag = np.array(g)
datab = np.array(b)

rm=0.4 # the value I would like to multiply all red pixels by

datar=datar.dot(rm) # this works, but turns the values in the array into floats
datar=datar.astype(int) # I was hoping this would solve it

im=Image.merge("RGB", (Image.fromarray(datar), Image.fromarray(datag), Image.fromarray(datab)))
```

I can do a lot of things with the arrays and the merge succeeds, but trying this gives me the following error:

```
im=Image.merge("RGB", (Image.fromarray(datar), Image.fromarray(datag), Image.fromarray(datab)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2408, in merge
im.putband(bands[i].im, i)
ValueError: images do not match
```

The array looks the same before and after the .dot and the .astype(int) are applied, and the values are multiplied correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image.merge` fails because rgb images are not of the same mode (see [PIL Image modes](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)). You can check the mode this way:

```
>>> Image.fromarray(datar).mode
'I'
>>> Image.fromarray(datag).mode
'L'
```

The reason for this is the type of the numpy array:

```
>>> datar.dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> datag.dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

To fix that, replace this:

```
datar=datar.astype(int)
```

with this:

```
datar = datar.astype('uint8')
```